# Export to Excel from SQL task

Tags: excel, ssis, business-intelligence

I need to extract information from Sybase database and the put it into Excel file. Due to this extraction uses subquery's I'm using a SQL Task to extract the information and put it into a variable (Data type = Object). So, I need to get the data from the variable and save it into an Excel file. Here what I have until now:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:
[image]
[image]

Then edit script and add the following code to main function:

```
Public Sub Main()
        '
        ' Add your code here
        '

        Dim varExcelApplication As Object
        Dim varExcelBook As Object
        Dim varExcelSheet As Object
        Dim varNumeroFila As Integer
        Dim varNumeroColumna As Integer
        Dim varResults As DataSet
        Dim varRow As DataRow
        Dim varColumn As DataColumn

        Try
            ' Crea la instancia de Excel
            varExcelApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            varExcelBook = varExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add()
            varExcelSheet = varExcelBook.ActiveSheet
            varExcelApplication.Visible = False
            varExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = False

            ' Carga los resultados del query
            varResults = CType(Dts.Variables("varRecordSetEstimaciones").Value, DataSet)

            For Each varTabla As DataTable In varResults.Tables
                varNumeroFila = 1
                For Each varRow In varTabla.Rows
                    varNumeroColumna = 1
                    For Each varColumn In varTabla.Columns
                        ' Añade la cabecera para la primera fila
                        If varNumeroFila = 1 Then
                            varExcelSheet.Cells(1, varNumeroColumna) = varColumn.ColumnName.ToString
                        End If
                        varExcelSheet.Cells(varNumeroFila + 1, varNumeroColumna) = varRow(varColumn.Ordinal).ToString
                        varNumeroColumna = varNumeroColumna + 1
                    Next
                    varNumeroFila = varNumeroFila + 1
                Next
            Next

            ' Guarda el archivo
            varExcelBook.SaveAs(Dts.Variables("varPath").Value.ToString & "\Estimaciones.xlsx")
            varExcelApplication.Workbooks.Close()
            varExcelApplication.Quit()

            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
        End Try

    End Sub
```